# How to access BindableProperty in PCL renderer from iOS customrenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Im trying to access my bindable property for a custom button that I attempt to code a renderer for. First here is my PCL renderer:

```
public class BtnRenderer : Button
{

    public static readonly BindableProperty HighLightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HighlightedBackgroundColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BtnRenderer), default(Color));

    public Color HighlightedBackgroundColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(HighLightProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HighLightProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I intend to set a `HighlightedBackgroundColor` from XAML, However, I don't know how to access it in my iOS renderer, what I have is:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BtnRenderer), typeof(BtnRendereriOS))]
namespace BluetoothExample.iOS
{
    public class BtnRendereriOS : ButtonRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var normalBackgroundColor = Element.BackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
                var _highlightBackgroundColor = Element.HighlightedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor(); //HERE IS MY PROBLEM

            async Task NormalColorState(UIButton button)
            {
                await UIView.TransitionNotifyAsync(button, .25, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, () =>
                {
                    button.BackgroundColor = normalBackgroundColor;
                });
            }
            Control.TouchDown += async (object sender, EventArgs c) =>
            {
                var button = sender as UIButton;
                await UIView.TransitionNotifyAsync(button, .25, UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve, () =>
                {
                    button.BackgroundColor = _highlightBackgroundColor;
                });
            };
        }
    }
}
```

How do I access this property correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
>
> var _highlightBackgroundColor = Element.HighlightedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor();

Directly using `Element` is the base of your renderer (`VisualElementRenderer<TElement>`) so in order to access any custom properties on your subclass, just cast it (`BtnRenderer` in this case):

```
var _highlightBackgroundColor = (Element as BtnRenderer).HighlightedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor();
```

Comment: It returns a null reference though when I release the button. (It reside in a modal View)

Comment: @JeppeChristensen I am not sure what you mean by that... is the View/VisualElement still valid? (not disposed/GC/...?)

Comment: I haven't used dispose anywhere. Might I do that?